# Using Cell Size in raster calculator (ModelBuilder)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I'm using ModelBuilder in ArcGis to create model which can calculate some stuff from my raster.

At some point I have to multiply raster value and raster cell size. I've created variable Cell Size, but it doesn't appear in Raster Calculator 'Layers and Variables'.

[image]

I could manually type value reffering to cell size, but it's not the point. In the future I'd like to use that model to make calculations on other raster with different cell size.

Does anyone know how to use Cell Size in raster calculator?

Answer (score 1):

Keeping this in your mind that the raster dataset may not always have square cells, you can use [Get Raster Properties](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/get-raster-properties.htm) tool within a [Calculate Value](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-value.htm) model only tool.

Assume the name of your DEM feature class/layer in your model is `MY_DEM` which has square cells. Then you can write Calculate Value's **Expression** part:

`float(arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management("%MY_DEM%", "CELLSIZEX")[0])`.

Last note, you need to define output of Calculate Value as ***variable*** and ***precondition*** to the subsequent tools. By default it generates an output name something generic, **Value**, and if you may rename this to something meaningful, say **MY_DEM_CELL_SIZE**, you can use this value by referencing to it as `%MY_DEM_CELL_SIZE%`